# Spark SQL for JDBC to fetch data from other database

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark

With new spark 1.3 published, I am excited to try the JDBC function (in Python). However, I think help is not optional this moment with the error I encountered:

Here is what I did:

1. I started with typical spark shell under scala like

   ```
   SPARK_CLASSPATH=/jdbc_path/some-jdbc-driver.jar bin/spark-shell
   ```

   and it turn out in the INFO: to use `--driver-class-path` (and I followed)
2. In PySpark REPEL, the relevant packages are imported and I used

   ```
   df2 = sqlCtx.load("jdbc", url="jdbc:ncluster://serveraddress:2406/database?user=myid&password=mypass", driver="com.asterdata.ncluster.Driver", dbtable="mytable")
   ```

But the error message kept showing no such file with spark_home/jdbc.

May I know:

1. When set up the additional external class, how do I know it is well included?
2. Just a simple JDBC linking to other database, is there any complete example to follow with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can go to Spark environment UI at http://localhost:4040/environment/ to check whether the jars are included or not.
2. I have faced the same problem(2), try:

   ```
   df2 = sqlCtx.load(source="jdbc", url="jdbc:ncluster://serveraddress:2406/database?user=myid&password=mypass", driver="com.asterdata.ncluster.Driver", dbtable="mytable")
   ```

Let me know if it works. In my case it worked, but still I am not able to make connection with my db because spark is not able to recognise my jar file. It sounds wierd, but it's happening somehow.

Please let me know if you are able to connect.

Comment: Hi! I am working on something similar. What's the difference between sqlCtx.load() and sqlContext.load()? Is one just an alias?

Comment: No difference, sqlCtx & sqlContext both are same. Just different variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting SPARK_CLASSPATH (at least on Spark 1.5.2 it says it's deprecated), try following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33767750/597349) and edit `conf/spark-defaults.conf` adding both lines below.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/to/my.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /path/to/my.jar
```

I didn't need to use `--driver-class-path`, because the jars will be loaded by default when Spark starts.