# Automatically including jars to PySpark classpath

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I'm trying to automatically include jars to my PySpark classpath. Right now I can type the following command and it works:

```
$ pyspark --jars /path/to/my.jar
```

I'd like to have that jar included by default so that I can only type `pyspark` and also use it in IPython Notebook.

I've read that I can include the argument by setting PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS in env:

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--jars /path/to/my.jar"
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work. I get the runtime error `Failed to load class for data source`.

Running Spark 1.3.1.

**Edit**

My workaround when using IPython Notebook is the following:

```
$ IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark --jars /path/to/my.jar
```

Comment: `Error in pyspark startup: IPYTHON and IPYTHON_OPTS are removed in Spark 2.0+. Remove these from the environment and set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS instead.`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add the jar files in the *spark-defaults.conf* file (located in the conf folder of your spark installation). If there is more than one entry in the jars list, use : as separator.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/to/my.jar
```

This property is documented in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/configuration.html#runtime-environment

Comment: I get an error: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)`

Comment: @FullStack me too, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, you have to import jars to both driver **AND** executor. So, you need to edit `conf/spark-defaults.conf` adding both lines below.

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/to/my.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /path/to/my.jar
```

When I went through this, I did not need any other parameters. I guess you will not need them too.

Comment: `spark.executor.extraClassPath` is only for backwards-compatibility (not sure at which point it changed) but in the current docs it states you don't need it unless you're running an older version: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way since Spark 2.0+ is to use 
`spark.driver.extraLibraryPath`
and `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/configuration.html#runtime-environment

ps. `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` are still there, 
but deprecated and will be removed in a future release of Spark.