# How to use mongo-spark connector in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I new to python. I am trying to create a Spark DataFrame from mongo collections.
for that I have selected **mongo-spark connector** *link*-> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark

I dont how to use this jar/git repo into my python standalone script.
I wish to know how can clone the repository so that i can use it in standalone pyspark script on Windows

Comment: You can download the releases from here: https://spark-packages.org/package/mongodb/mongo-spark. How to use this connector is described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/

Comment: Yes I got that...however I am developing the script in PyCharm and not pyspark.. thats the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically including jars to PySpark classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464845/automatically-including-jars-to-pyspark-classpath)

Comment: Sorry @VikrantSonawane I didn't get this. PyCharm is an IDE while pyspark is a framework/library

Comment: apologies for the ambiguity.. I am trying it to work on Pycharm IDE and not the pyspark shell.. I am not able to understand the setup process as I new to Python.. I am used to Maven repo for these things

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still struggling with this. What worked for me in the end was the following configuration (Setting up or configuring your mongo-spark-connector):

MongoDb version 3.4.14; 
Spark version 2.2.1; 
Scala version 2.11.8;

**Jars:**

[mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.1.jar](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.1/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.1.jar), [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.4.2/mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar), [mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.2/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar), [bson-3.4.2.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.4.2/bson-3.4.2.jar),

Using the correct **Spark**, **Scala** versions with the correct **mongo-spark-connector** jar version is obviously key here including all the correct versions of the **mongodb-driver-core**, **bson** and **mongo-java-driver** jars.

I had to inspect the [pom.xml](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.1/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.1.pom) on Maven Central of the version of **mongo-spark-connector** I needed to see which version of **mongo-java-driver** I needed and then downloaded the corresponding **mongodb-driver-core** and **bson** jars subsequently.

Finally test: Scala

```
spark-shell --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://<username>:<password>@<server>/<database>.<collection>?readPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://mongodb://<username>:<password>@<server>/<database>.<collection>" --jars <path to jar>/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.1.jar,<path to jar>/mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar,<path to jar>/bson-3.4.2.jar,<path to jar>/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar

scala> import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark._

scala> val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
println(rdd.count)
```

test pyspark: Example using aggregate pipeline

```
pyspark --jars <path to jar>/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.1.jar,<path to jar>/mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar,<path to jar>/bson-3.4.2.jar,<path to jar>/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar

In [1]: stage1="{'$match':{'_id':ObjectId('<SOME UID>')}}"
In [2]: df=spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri","mongodb://<username>:<password>@<server><database>.<collection>").option("pipeline",stage1).load()
In [3]: df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below let me know if it helps

```
hadoop2.7$ mongod --version

db version v3.6.8

hadoop2.7$ bin/pyspark --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0

https://github.com/mak705/Spark_NoSql_Connector/blob/master/Mongo_Spark.ipynb
```